# How to get the plaintext of a Secret Key Entry in Mozilla NSSDB PKCS11?

Tags: java, key, mozilla, pkcs#11

I have a mozilla NSSDB PKCS11, it includes one of three things. Certificates, keys, and SecretKeyEntry. I would like to know the content of a SecretKeyEntry with the alias "StoreXKey". Firstly, is extracting the plaintext of a SecretKeyEntry possible? I seem to think so because of links: https://technosock.blogspot.com/2007/12/token-knowledge.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry.html#getSecretKey

First link gives a way to do it ( which doesn't work for me ) the second link gives us a few methods, namely .getEncoded() which can supposedly be called on a SecretKeyEntry to get the byte array information.

Here is my code thus far, all results hit a null pointer exception when using the getEncoded message. I am sure the SecretKeyEntry exists in the NSSDB.

```
String configFile = "config.cfg";
Provider provider = Security.getProvider("SunPKCS11"); // I am confused on how to incorporate the config file as well.
/* provider = provider.configure(configFile); // Does not work */
Security.addProvider(provider);

String defaultPIN = "--.--.--.--.----.-...-.--";
try{
   KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11");
   ks.load(null, defaultPIN.toCharArray());
   KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry skEntry = (KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry) ks.getEntry("StoreXKey",null); // Do I need a password protector here?
   System.out.println(new String(skEntry.getSecretKey().getEncoded())); <-- Error is thrown here. 
}catch (Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Any help / advice or links are appreciated.

Comment: To extract secret key from provider in most cases you need first to `wrap` it. It is not a single-line command, but it is sequence of several calls to `PKCS#11` module.

Comment: @Alexander Do you mean wrapping it as a Key?

Comment: Yes. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22663457/3868464).

Comment: @Alexander this doesn't really help me because mine is with an NSS db and not a swap.